# Why is my Stopwatch not adding time?

Tags: c#, .net, class, static, stopwatch

The class won't add on to the Stopwatch time using Speedrun.AddToTime(h, m, s)

No clue as to why!

```
class Speedrun
    {
        private static Stopwatch sr = new Stopwatch();

        public static void Go()
        {
            sr.Reset();
            sr.Start();
        }

        public static string GetTime
        {
            get
            {
                return sr.Elapsed.Hours + "h " + sr.Elapsed.Minutes + "m " + sr.Elapsed.Seconds + "s";
            }

        }

        public static void AddToTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
        {
            TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, seconds);
            sr.Elapsed.Add(ts);

        }

        public static void Stop()
        {
            sr.Stop();
        }

        public static void Cont()
        {
            sr.Start();
        }
    }
```

Fairly straight forward, I'm referencing it using the class name itself, instead of a variable. As seen here

```
Speedrun.Go();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE!!**

CHEAP solution found here it is to help you guys that might have the similar situation

```
class Speedrun
{
    private static Stopwatch sr = new Stopwatch();

    private static int addedhours = 0;
    private static int addedminutes = 0;
    private static int addedseconds = 0;


    public static void Go()
    {
        sr.Reset();
        sr.Start();
        addedhours = 0;
        addedminutes = 0;
        addedseconds = 0;
    }

    public static string GetTime
    {
        get
        {
            return (sr.Elapsed.Hours + addedhours) + "h " + (sr.Elapsed.Minutes + addedminutes) + "m " + (sr.Elapsed.Seconds + addedseconds) + "s";
        }

    }

    public static void AddToTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
    {
        addedhours = addedhours + hours;
        addedminutes = addedminutes + minutes;
        addedseconds = addedseconds + seconds;

    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        sr.Stop();
    }

    public static void Cont()
    {
        sr.Start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You're calling `Add` on a `TimeSpan`. `TimeSpan` is an *immutable* value type. You're doing nothing with the result here:

```
sr.Elapsed.Add(ts);
```

... so it's effectively a no-op. Even if `TimeSpan` were immutable, it's still a value type - so you'd be fetching the property value (which would make a copy), then calling `Add`, and the mutated copy would then be lost.

Basically, what you're trying to do here won't work.

EDIT: Your workaround doesn't really work either, because if it's taken 35 seconds and you're adding 30 seconds, you'll end up reporting 65 seconds instead of 1 minutes and 5 seconds.

You should keep just a `TimeSpan` to add, then you can use something like:

```
public static string GetTime
{
    get
    {
        TimeSpan time = sr.Elapsed + timeToAdd;
        // In .NET 4 you could use a custom format string for the TimeSpan
        return string.Format("{0}h {1}m {2}s",
                             time.Hours, time.Minutes, time.Seconds);
    }
}
```

I'm somewhat dubious of the overall design though - in particular, all these statics without any attempt at thread-safety makes me nervous... Do you really *need* all of this to be static to start with?

Comment: `Even if TimeSpan were immutable` er, you mean mutable?

Comment: Ohhhh, I see. But still can't figure out a bloody solution. I did however come up with one that is cheap, which works the same way. I'll post it.

Comment: @user537156: Your solution is a bit broken. I'll edit to suggest an alternative...

Answer (score 1):

`StopWatch.Elapsed` returns a new `TimeSpan` object. Calling `Add` on that object creates yet another `TimeSpan` object, which you then discard.

You're not writing anything back to your `StopWatch` object.

Try this:

```
class Speedrun
{
    private static Stopwatch sr = new Stopwatch();
    private static TimeSpan elapsed = new TimeSpan();

    public static void Go()
    {
        elapsed = new TimeSpan(0);
        sr.Reset();
        sr.Start();
    }

    public static string GetTime
    {
        get
        {
            elapsed = elapsed.Add(sr.Elapsed);
            return elapsed.Hours + "h " + elapsed.Minutes + "m " + elapsed.Seconds + "s";
        }

    }

    public static void AddToTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
    {
        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, seconds);
        elapsed = elapsed.Add(ts);
    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        sr.Stop();
    }

    public static void Cont()
    {
        sr.Start();
    }
}
```

FYI, `GetTime` is an appropriate name for a *method*. A better name for a *property* would simply be `Time` or `ElapsedTime`.

Comment: All he really needs to do is give his class a `TimeSpan` member, put the result of `sr.Elapsed.Add(ts);` into that, and then reference it instead of the StopWatch in the `GetTime` method...

Answer (score 1):

TimeSpan.Add() doesn't modify the existing value, but returns a new resultant TimeSpan. So you'll need to change:

```
sr.Elapsed.Add(ts);
```

... so that it actually stores the result somewhere useful.

Comment: That stores the result in a temporary object which is then discarded.

Comment: @Mud:  It doesn't _have_ to.  The author would need to handle that logic outside of the Stopwatch.

Comment: @MUd what are you talking about? I said the OP needs to store the result somewhere useful. I was quoting their current code, not the code to change to. Please read responses carefully, especially before handing out negative reputation.

Comment: @itsme86 Gotcha. Can't retract my vote unless you edit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution...

```
public class StopwatchPlus : Stopwatch
{
    private TimeSpan AddedTime { get; set; }
    public StopwatchPlus() { AddedTime = new TimeSpan(0); }
    public TimeSpan Elapsed { get { return base.Elapsed.Add(AddedTime); } }
    public void Add(TimeSpan time) { AddedTime = AddedTime.Add(time); }
}
```

Comment: The Elapsed field should be declared as following: public new TimeSpan Elapsed { get => base.Elapsed.Add(AddedTime); }

Answer (score 0):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.add.aspx

Add returns a new TimeSpan object rather than mutating the existing, and since StopWatch.Elapsed is readonly I don't know if you can accomplish what you're trying